# Why are charts of EXPO different?

Tags: stocks

I found that charts and prices for EXPO (Exponent Inc.) on TradingView and other websites are different.

Below is the EXPO chart from WSJ (http://quotes.wsj.com/EXPO).

[image: WSJ EXPO Chart]

Below is the EXPO chart from TradingView (https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=EXPO).

[image: TradingView EXPO Chart]

As you can see, 2 charts are very different at the end. WSJ one is fairly stable ($43) but TradingView one dropped nearly $40 (from $84.57 to $43.43).

Is there a glitch or it's my misunderstanding? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Exponent](http://www.exponent.com/Exponent-Announces-Two-for-One-Stock-Split-and-Declares-Regular-Quarterly-Dividend-04-22-2015/) announced a 2-1 stock split that likely is factored into the top graph but not the bottom would be my thinking.

Comment: Yes the first chart shows the split adjusted prices whilst the second chart shows the actual prices. To anyalise the trend you would use the split adjusted chart.